# How to get basic statistics such as sum, mean, median, max and min from list created from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am VERY NEW to programming, and Freshly new to python. I've read in a csv file of two columns and I am looking to find the mean, median, max and min of the second column. I managed to get max and min, but I run into trouble with sum. I'm sure the issue is mostly "syntactic" (is that a word).

```py
with open(pybankfile, newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    # @NOTE: This time, we do not use `next(csv_reader)` because there is no header for this file

    # Read the header row first (skip this step if there is now header)
    csv_header = next(csvfile)
    lst =[]
    print(f"CSV Header: {csv_header}")
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = list(reader)
    maxnum = max(data, key=lambda row: int(row[1]))
    minnum = min(data, key=lambda row: int(row[1]))
    tot = sum(data)  *#fails here
    # print(f"maximum: {maxnum}")
    print(data)
    sum()
    print(f"minimum: {minnum}")
    print(f"maximum: {maxnum}")
    print(f"Balance: {tot}")
```

Comment: tot = sum(data,row: int(row[1]))
Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
#add your file here
with open('examplefile.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

#list comprehension to extract the second column
second_column = [int(row[1]) for row in data]

#Built in functions in python 
maxnum = max(second_column)
minnum = min(second_column)
sumcol = sum(second_column)

#The mean is the sum divided by the length
meancol = sumcol/int(len(second_column))

#Median

#We create a new sorted list, while keeping the original unchanged
sorted_second_column = sorted(second_column)

col_length = len(second_column)
index = (col_length - 1) // 2
if col_length % 2 == 0:
    mediancol = ((second_column[index] + second_column[index + 1])/2.0)
else:
    mediancol = second_column[index]

print(maxnum, minnum, sumcol, meancol, mediancol)
```

Comment: Can you have a go at explaining your solution? How does it differ from the OP's attempt - where did they go wrong?

Comment: Well, I think there is nothing especially wrong with the attempt, it's just that everything seems chaotic and the lack of experience is obvious. I tried explaining what I did in the comments of the code.

Comment: Antonjmkd I appreciate the guidance and critique. Thank you!

Comment: AntonijMKD I love this simple, elegant solution. How can I subtract consecutive values from each other in the column ?

Answer (score 0):

I create a CSV file by the below content,

```
col1, col2
1,2
1,2
3,5
8,5
```

You can solve the problem by the following code,

```
import csv

csvfile = 'data.csv'
data = dict()
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            data[0] = []
            data[1] = []
            line_count += 1
        else:
            data[0].append(int(row[0]))
            data[1].append(int(row[1]))
            line_count += 1
        print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')

maxnum = max(data[1])
minnum = min(data[1])
tot = sum(data[1])
print(data)
print(f"minimum: {minnum}")
print(f"maximum: {maxnum}")
print(f"Balance: {tot}")
```

however, I recommend using Pandas for reading and working with CSV files. you can find a complete tutorial for Pandas in the following link:
[pandas tutorial](https://realpython.com/pandas-read-write-files/)

Also for mean, average, median, I recommend using NumPy, you can find a tutorial for NumPy in the following link,
[numpy tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_statistical_functions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **pandas** package because it's easier for beginners and used even by professionals. You can achieve the same thing as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")

df.describe()
```

The describe method will show you all the statistics

if you just want to select specific column, do this:

```
df[df.columns[1]].describe() #second column
```

if you know the column name:

```
df['column name'].describe()
```

if you only need to know, for instance the `mean` of the second column, do this:

```
df[df.columns[1]].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to the python, try learning libraries like numpy and pandas.. There you will be covered by maximum of things you want to do..

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.read_csv("csv_file.csv")

    data.describe()
```

you will get an output something like this

```
count    3.0
mean     2.0
std      1.0
min      1.0
25%      1.5
50%      2.0
75%      2.5
max      3.0
dtype: float64
```

You can go and read from this link [pandas .describe() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html)